# Using htaccess to redirect http://www, http:// and https://www to https:

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On my site I have installed an SSL certificate on the non www version of the domain.  I would like to use htaccess to redirect http www, http non www and https www to https://

I have the www to non www working but the https www does not redirect to https non www.  Here is what I have in my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ link [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https link [R,L]
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing?

Sharon

Comment: For some reason it wouldn't let me post the actual links so I replaced them with "Link".  Thanks!

Comment: Turns out that now I need to do the opposite.  To Redirect http www, http non www and https non www to https://www.  How do I change that around? Is there an answer I can refer to for that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes - one rule that will redirect http www, http non www and https non www to https www.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: for http or https, with or without www -> **https without www**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And for the opposite: for http or https, with or without www -> **https with www**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Turns out that now I need to the the opposite.  To Redirect http www, http non www and https non www to https://www.  How do I change that around?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should this https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} be replaced with the actual domain so https://www.domain.com

Comment: No, it's automatic, you do not have to change anything

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments here is one single rule to do following redirects in single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This does:

```
http://www.domain.com/foobar  => https://www.domain.com/foobar
http://domain.com/foobar      => https://www.domain.com/foobar
https://domain.com/foobar     => https://www.domain.com/foobar
https://www.domain.com/foobar => Unchanged
```

Comment: What is the `%1%` for?

Comment: That is back reference for captured group in RewriteCond

Comment: Best solution I've come across so far as it doesn't require hard-coding the domain name. Thank you