# How to redirect all traffic to non www https with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, lets-encrypt

I have domain registered in ovh. My site files are stored in folder called "www" in root directory. It was original ovh setup. A few days ago I discovered that i can use let's encrypt ssl certyficate. Now I have these addresses:

```
example.com,
www.example.com,
https://example.com,
https://www.example.com
```

I want to redirect:

```
example.com
www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

to:

```
https://example.com
```

via .htaccess 301 redirection

I tried a lot of sample htaccess redirections from this and other sites. Non of them work perfectly for me.

For example redirection from `example.com to https://example.com` was ok, but from `www.example.com`take me to`https://www.example.com/www`or`https://www.example.com` with browser warning "unsafe content".

It is harder than i thought.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27528864/1741542 for a very good answer.

Comment: I used this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27528864/1741542 but when i go to `https://www.example.com` i still have browser warning.

Comment: I don't know what this "unsafe content" means. Maybe it is a certificate warning. When the certificate is only issued for example.com and not www.example.com, this might be a reason. But "unsafe content" is very vague, this might also point to mixed content or something else. But whatever it is, I think it has nothing to do with these rewrite rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using htaccess to redirect http://www, http:// and https://www to https:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528597/using-htaccess-to-redirect-http-www-http-and-https-www-to-https)

Comment: Presumably you mean from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`, it help to provide full URLs in such a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wordpress, you could install a simple pulgin called **Really Simple SSl** which will automatically do this redirection.