# how can we properly redirect www and non-www http urls to https in htaccess without multiple 301s?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

we are trying to 301 redirect all of our http www urls and http non-www urls to the https version.

Right now the 301 redirects are happening but there are multiple 301s occurring.

Right now: 
    http://www >>301> http:// >>301>> https://
    http://example.com/contact-us >>301>>https://example.com/contact-us >>301>> to the https version with a closing slash.

How can we write the htaccess file so there is only 1 301 redirect for each version of the website?

Here is how we have the htaccess file set up which is causing multiple 301s and i do not understand why.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are showing only one 301 rule. Are there more rules? Which URL is showing multiple 301?

Comment: There has to be a separate rule somewhere that is removing `www`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27528864/1741542 for a very good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using htaccess to redirect http://www, http:// and https://www to https:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528597/using-htaccess-to-redirect-http-www-http-and-https-www-to-https)

Comment: I tried using the htaccess file code from the linked document: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27528864/1741542 and it did not solve the issues.  The htaccess file code i provided is what i have written in the file.  The problem is that the http www example. com/contact-us 301s to http example. com/contact-us/ then 301s to https example. com/contact-us  so how can we 301 everything to the https example version without trailing slashes? How can we keep just 1 version of the url, with no slashes at the end?